# JQuery .click function not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm just starting with JQuery and generally web development, so this question might be really easy but I would appreciate your help.

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#convbut").click(function() {
        alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
      });
  });
```

HTML button:

```
<button name="conversion" type="button" id="#convbut">Convert</button>
```

When clicking Convert button I am not getting alert message.

Comment: `id="#convbut"` !! `id="convbut"`

Comment: Check id of the button

Comment: it didn't help.

Comment: remove "#" from button id

Comment: I removed and it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what error you have in your console. Make sure you have loaded the jquery library first. I have added full code here so as you haven't and is working great
.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button name="conversion" type="button" id="convbut">Convert</button>

    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#convbut").click(function(){
          alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
        });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't get any kind of errors in console. I know it should work and that's why I am wondering what's wrong and want to identify the problem :)

Comment: why don't you post full code so that the error could be replicated

Answer (score 0):

Your html

```
<button name="conversion" type="button" id="#convbut">Convert</button>
```

use this by remove # before id;

```
<button name="conversion" type="button" id="convbut">Convert</button>
```

Comment: I realized the problem, I need HASH in JQuery before ID name without ID actually having it in index.html

Answer (score 0):

I realized the problem, I need HASH in JQuery before ID name without ID actually having it in index.html

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#convbut").click(function() {
        alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
      });
  });
```

HTML:

```
<button name="conversion" type="button" id="convbut">Convert</button>
```